# How to loop a function in a other function in Python Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, jupyter-notebook

My desired code is:

```
def clustering_data(n):
      for i in n:
            di = dd(i)
            DF = [d0, d1, d2, d3,...,d(n-1)]
            df = pd.concat(DF)
      return df
```

Here,

- n = integer number.
- di = It will iterate and run dd[i] functions from i=0 to i=n times.
- dd[i] = It is another function of our project.
- DF = Merging all data set of dd[i]
- df = Final merged data-set

For example, if n is 5, my desire that the loop would generate following processes:

```
def clustering_data(5):
      for i in 5:
            d0 = dd(0)
            d1 = dd(1)
            d2 = dd(2)
            d3 = dd(3)
            d4 = dd(4)
            DF = [d0, d1, d2, d3, d4]
            df = pd.concat(DF)
      return df
```

Actually, I would like to run the dd[i] function in i=1 to i=n times. Each loop will generate di data set (d0,d1,d2,....). Then I will combine the all di data-sets (d0,d1,d2....).

I need your valuable opinion and suggestion in this regard.

N.B.: `dd(value)` is a function which need one integer to execute.

And this is my first question in the Stack Overflow. I apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: `for i in 5:` should be `for i in range(5):` in second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's great! Your desired pseudocode is almost directly translatable to valid syntax:

```
def clustering_data(n):
    DF = [dd(i) for i in range(n)]
    df = pd.concat(DF)
    return df
```

That is, assuming I'm understanding your intentions correctly. The above will make `df` the result of concatenating `n` data frames. Your pseudocode would have produced sum(i for i in range(n)) data frames to concat.

Some tips:

- Look up [list comprehensions](https://www.learnpython.org/en/List_Comprehensions)
- The fact that you're in a Jupyter notebook doesn't change how this function works (leaving that out of your question description would likely attract a wider set of potential answer-ers)

Comment: Thank you so much `@augray` you save my day. You are a genius.

Comment: @KindDAnonymous: No problem! The way you say "thanks" on Stack Overflow is with an upvote and/or a "mark as answer" :-)

Comment: how do mark as answer :( ?  I have tick marked your comment.